# Replace content file in ruby

Tags: ruby, file, replace, directory

I would like to replace some text with whitespaces and spaces in ruby in all files.

```
toReplace = [

'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\"
\"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">
<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" lang=\"pl\" xml:lang=\"pl\"> 

<head>'
]

replacement = [

'<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">'
]
```

I use gsub for this, but it doesn't work because there is problem with whitespaces and spaces.

```
contents.gsub! toReplace[i], replacement[i]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do a conversion to html5. If you are see http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_migration.asp

Comment: You might consider using [nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) for parsing your webpage and for outputing your new html page.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, and "[mcve]". We expect to see more than two array assignments. What have you tried? If you haven't why not? Currently it looks like you're asking us to write the code for you.

Comment: Are all files you're processing guaranteed to have the exact same lines at the top, including line-breaks? If so, you could use `sub`. If not, you need to use Nokogiri, which is a more robust solution as @zhon said.

Answer (score 0):

You could try escaping the first string to avoid any characters being treated as special:

```
REPLACE = Regexp.escape(%Q[<!DOCTYPE...
])

WITH = %Q[
  ...
]

contents.gsub!(REPLACE, WITH)
```

Note that you should be using either a string or a regular expression, not an array as you have in your code.